# Plugin makes application crash

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a Cordova app for iOS. I am fairly new to this environment and these tools. I am looking for someone who can give me any ideas for how to solve a problem that I am stuck on.

This app uses a number of plugins. One of the others is causing a crash at app start. It builds without any issues. I can not see anything in any log file except "safe quit" and I wonder if anyone can suggest a way to find out what is causing the crash so that I can fix it or tell the plugin developer what the issue is and ask him to fix it.

The plugins works with audio streaming, and is build on top of LFLiveKit.

Out of all the plugins used, this one is the only one that is linked in via pods. See attachment.

When this plugin is removed, the app builds and runs just fine.

Can anyone please suggest something I can try to make progress on this?

Plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<plugin xmlns='http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0' id='com.cqrify.streamingplugin' version='1.0'>
  <name>
     streamingplugin 
  </name>
  <engines>
    <engine name='cordova' version='>=3.4.0'/>
  </engines>
  <asset src='www/streamingPlugin.js' target='js/streamingPlugin.js'/>
  <js-module src='www/streamingPlugin.js' name='streamingPlugin'>
    <clobbers target='streamingPlugin'/>
  </js-module>
  <platform name='ios'>
    <config-file target='config.xml' parent='/*'>
      <feature name='StreamingPlugin'>
        <param name='ios-package' value='CDVAudioStreamingPlugin'/>
      </feature>
    </config-file>
    <header-file src='src/ios/AlarmStream.h'/>
    <header-file src='src/ios/AlarmStreamHandler.h'/>
    <header-file src='src/ios/StreamingPlugin.h'/>
    <source-file src='src/ios/AlarmStream.m'/>
    <source-file src='src/ios/StreamingPlugin.m'/>
    <framework src='LFLiveKit' type='podspec' spec='2.6'/>
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

StreamingPlugin.podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
spec.name         = 'StreamingPlugin'
spec.version      = '1.1'
spec.requires_arc = true
spec.platform     = :ios, '9.0'
spec.source       = {:path => '.'}
spec.source_files = 'src/ios/*.{h,m}'
spec.public_header_files = 'src/ios/*.h'

spec.dependency 'LFLiveKit'
spec.dependency 'Cordova'
end
```